# Set default value for static method in bootstrap

Tags: zend-framework, static, lucene, bootstrapping

this paragraph is part of 'Zend Framework In Action' book.

```
SearchIndexer::setIndexDirectory(ROOT_DIR . '/var/search_index');
Places_Db_Table_Row_Observable::attachObserver('SearchIndexer');
```

**As you can see, it’s simply a case of setting the directory to store the search index files
and attaching the class to the list of observers in Places_Db_Table_Row_Observable
using the name of the class.**

Now I have a problem! I put this code in bootstrap file in runapp method, but  it can't recognize the directory that I set in bootstrap!

It shows me this error

```
An error occurred exception 'Zend_Search_Exception' with message 'No index directory specified' in E:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Search\Lucene.php:497
```

=======================================================

**other type of my question :**

I have this code in bootstrap file (runApp method):

```
SearchIndexer::setIndexDirectory(ROOT_DIR.'/var/search_index');  
Places_Db_Table_Row_Observable::attachObserver('SearchIndexer');
```

I set search directory path in SearchIndexer class, but there is a prob!

When I use of below code in controller action, it can't recognize the directory that I set in bootstrap!

controller code :

```
$index = Places_Search_Lucene::open(SearchIndexer::getIndexDirectory());
```

this is seachIndexer code :

```
public static function setIndexDirectory($directory){
    if(!is_dir($directory)) {
        throw new Exception('Directory for SearchIndexer is invalid ('. $directory .')');
    }
    self::$_indexDirectory = $directory;
}

public static function getIndexDirectory(){
    return self::$_indexDirectory;
}
```

Comment: regardless of your question, try Solr search engine, it is so muuuuuuuch better ;)

Comment: are you sure the method in your bootstrap got executed ? methods in bootstrap should be called _initSomething() AFAIR

Comment: And how did you define `$_indexDirectory` in SearchIndexer? Did you turn on PHP error logging and check the logs for errors/warnings/notices? And finally what version of PHP are you using 5.2 or 5.3?

Comment: ya , you`re right. it don`t execute . i have to put my code after frontcontroller dispactch execute, because model directory set in frontcontroler and searchindexer is in model directory! so where must be my code? afte dispatch code in runapp metod it don`t work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getIndexDirectory` function does not return a path so `Places_Search_Lucene::open` fails.

Maybe `setIndexDirectory` fails to set the path. Do some **debugging** on that.

---

Maybe you use the class in your bootstrap before it gets loaded by zend autoloader. Where do you perform this?

Try to load the class manually before usage:

```
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Path_To_SearchIndexer',
    array(
        '/home/production/mylib',
    )
);
```

Documentation on zend loader: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.load.html

Comment: i debuge that! when i put that code in action metod, directory set without prob . but i need set directory in bootstap beacuse i need to that in models and this code `Places_Db_Table_Row_Observable::attachObserver('SearchIndexer');
` must be set in bootstarp

Comment: i want don`t use of zend_loader in my code, for example a method that will run after runapp and i put my code in it ,is there any way?

Comment: This would be a right way to do it. Zend autoloader, which is performed in the _initAutoload method, has to be initialized before you can use your classes

Comment: ok, thanx a lot . this question was really expensive for me ;)

Comment: Click on the blue button to asign the bounty to my answer ;)